# Visual Studio Cordova plugins dont get included in iOS build

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015

Ok, I've been working on this problem all day. I started a skeleton Cordova app in Visual Studio 2015, installed the cordova-plugin-device and cordova-plugin-dialog plugins. I don't have any code, I just put a javascript breakpoint after the onDeviceReady event fires and I look for the *navigator.notification* or the *device* variables, and they are always *undefined*.

I've got device debugging setup with a physical **android** device, and everything works great, both variables are initialized and the plugins are available to use.  But I've also got iOS remote debugging setup to a physical iPhone, however both variables are *undefined* no matter what I try when running on the iPhone.

I **think** for some reason the iOS isn't actually including the plugins in the build. Take a look at this (partial) build log.  You will notice a *Currently installed plugins* line that mentions the device, dialog, and whitelist plugins. But further down there is a *Fetching plugin* line that mentions the whitelist plugin, but neither of the other two are mentioned anywhere else in the build log.

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: BlankCordovaApp3, Configuration: Debug iOS ------
1>  ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
1>  JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55
1>  Running: C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp3\platforms\android\gradlew clean -b C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp3\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
1>  :clean UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:clean UP-TO-DATE
1>
1>  BUILD SUCCESSFUL
1>
1>  Total time: 2.621 secs
1>  Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.2 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.13
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>  ------ Cordova tools 5.3.3 already installed.
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBldDir: C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp3\bld\iOS\Debug
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBinDir: C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp3\bin\iOS\Debug
1>  ------    buildCommand: build
1>  ------    platform: iOS
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: ios
1>  ------    configuration: Debug
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------    projectName: BlankCordovaApp3
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp3
1>  ------    npmInstallDir: C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\npm
1>  ------    buildServerUrl: https://192.168.15.152:3000/cordova
1>  ------    buildTarget: iOSRemoteDevice
1>  ------    language: en-US
1>  ------ Platform ios already exists
1>  ------ Updating plugins
1>  ------ Currently installed plugins: cordova-plugin-device@1.0.1,cordova-plugin-dialogs@1.1.1,cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.0.0
1>  ------ Currently installed dependent plugins:
1>  ------ Currently configured plugins: cordova-plugin-device@1.0.1,cordova-plugin-dialogs@1.1.1
1>  ------ Incremental Build: false
1>  ------ Submitting new build request to: https://192.168.15.152:3000/cordova/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=5.3.3&cfg=debug&options=--device&loglevel=warn
1>  ------ New Build information: {"command":"build","vcordova":"5.3.3","cfg":"debug","options":"--device","loglevel":"warn","status":"Uploaded","buildCommand":"build","buildPlatform":"ios","configuration":"debug","buildLang":"en-US","buildDir":"/Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580","buildNumber":11580,"logLevel":0,"submissionTime":"2015-10-24T04:43:59.343Z","changeList":null,"buildSuccessful":false,"messageArgs":null,"message":"Uploaded build request payload.","tgzFilePath":"/Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/upload_11580.tgz","appDir":"/Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp","statusTime":"2015-10-24T04:43:59.524Z"}
1>  ------ 11:43:54 PM Checking on build status from https://192.168.15.152:3000/cordova/build/tasks/11580 [Attempt 1]
1>  uploaded - Uploaded build request payload.
1>  ------ 11:43:59 PM Checking on build status from https://192.168.15.152:3000/cordova/build/tasks/11580 [Attempt 2]
1>  building - Compiling.
1>  ------ 11:44:04 PM Checking on build status from https://192.168.15.152:3000/cordova/build/tasks/11580 [Attempt 3]
1>  complete - Build completed successfully.
1>  ------ Remote build log follows
1>  cordova platform add ios
1>  No version supplied. Retrieving version from config.xml...
1>  Adding ios project...
1>  Running command: /Users/myuser/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-ios/3.9.1/package/bin/create --cli /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios io.cordova.myappc385ac BlankCordovaApp3
1>  iOS project created with cordova-ios@3.9.1
1>  Command finished with error code 0: /Users/myuser/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-ios/3.9.1/package/bin/create --cli,/Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios,io.cordova.myappc385ac,BlankCordovaApp3
1>  Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "ios"
1>  Calling plugman.prepare for platform "ios"
1>  Preparing ios project
1>  Processing configuration changes for plugins.
1>  Iterating over installed plugins:
1>  Writing out cordova_plugins.js...
1>  Wrote out iOS Bundle Identifier to "io.cordova.myappc385ac"
1>  Wrote out iOS Bundle Version to "1.0.0"
1>  Copying icon from /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/res/icons/ios/icon-60.png to /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3/Resources/icons/icon-60.png
1>  Copying icon from /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png to /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3/Resources/icons/icon-60@2x.png
1>  Copying icon from /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/res/icons/ios/icon-60-3x.png to /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3/Resources/icons/icon-60@3x.png
1>  Copying icon from /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/res/icons/ios/icon-76.png to /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3/Resources/icons/icon-76.png
1>  Copying icon from /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png to /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3/Resources/icons/icon-76@2x.png
1>  Copying icon from /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/res/icons/ios/icon-small.png to /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3/Resources/icons/icon-small.png
1>  Copying icon from /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/res/icons/ios/icon-small-2x.png to /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3/Resources/icons/icon-small@2x.png
1>  Copying icon from /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/res/icons/ios/icon-40.png to /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3/Resources/icons/icon-40.png
1>  Copying icon from /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png to /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3/Resources/icons/icon-40@2x.png
1>  Copying icon from /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/res/icons/ios/icon-57.png to /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3/Resources/icons/icon.png
1>  Copying icon from /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/res/icons/ios/icon-57-2x.png to /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3/Resources/icons/icon@2x.png
1>  Copying icon from /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/res/icons/ios/icon-72.png to /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3/Resources/icons/icon-72.png
1>  Copying icon from /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/res/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png to /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3/Resources/icons/icon-72@2x.png
1>  Copying icon from /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/res/icons/ios/icon-50.png to /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3/Resources/icons/icon-50.png
1>  Copying icon from /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/res/icons/ios/icon-50-2x.png to /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3/Resources/icons/icon-50@2x.png
1>  Copying splash from /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png to /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3/Resources/splash/Default~iphone.png
1>  Copying splash from /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png to /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3/Resources/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png
1>  Copying splash from /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png to /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3/Resources/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png
1>  Copying splash from /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png to /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3/Resources/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png
1>  Copying splash from /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png to /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3/Resources/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png
1>  Copying splash from /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png to /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3/Resources/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png
1>  Copying splash from /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-568h-2x.png to /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3/Resources/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png
1>  Copying splash from /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png to /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3/Resources/splash/Default-667h.png
1>  Copying splash from /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png to /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3/Resources/splash/Default-736h.png
1>  Copying splash from /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png to /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3/Resources/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png
1>  iOS Product Name has not changed (still "BlankCordovaApp3")
1>  Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" in config.xml. Installing to the project
1>  Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist@1"
1>  Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist@1" via npm
1>  Copying plugin "/Users/myuser/.npm/cordova-plugin-whitelist/1.0.0/package" => "/Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist"
1>  Calling plugman.install on plugin "/Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist" for platform "ios" with options "{"cli_variables":{},"browserify":false,"pluginInfoProvider":{"_cache":{"/Users/myuser/.npm/cordova-plugin-whitelist/1.0.0/package":{"filepath":"/Users/myuser/.npm/cordova-plugin-whitelist/1.0.0/package/plugin.xml","dir":"/Users/myuser/.npm/cordova-plugin-whitelist/1.0.0/package","_et":{"_root":{"_id":893,"tag":"plugin","attrib":{"xmlns":"http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0","id":"cordova-plugin-whitelist","version":"1.0.0"},"text":"\n    ","tail":null,"_children":[{"_id":894,"tag":"name","attrib":{},"text":"Whitelist","tail":"\n    ","_children":[]},{"_id":895,"tag":"description","attrib":{},"text":"Cordova Network Whitelist Plugin","tail":"\n    ","_children":[]},{"_id":896,"tag":"license","attrib":{},"text":"Apache 2.0","tail":"\n    ","_children":[]},{"_id":897,"tag":"keywords","attrib":{},"text":"cordova,whitelist,policy","tail":"\n\n    ","_children":[]},{"_id":898,"tag":"engines","attrib":{},"text":"\n      ","tail":"\n\n    ","_children":[{"_id":899,"tag":"engine","attrib":{"name":"cordova-android","version":">=4.0.0-dev"},"text":"","tail":"\n    ","_children":[]}]},{"_id":900,"tag":"platform","attrib":{"name":"android"},"text":"\n        ","tail":"\n","_children":[{"_id":901,"tag":"config-file","attrib":{"target":"res/xml/config.xml","parent":"/*"},"text":"\n            ","tail":"\n\n        ","_children":[{"_id":902,"tag":"feature","attrib":{"name":"Whitelist"},"text":"\n                ","tail":"\n        ","_children":[{"_id":903,"tag":"param","attrib":{"name":"android-package","value":"org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin"},"text":"","tail":"\n                ","_children":[]},{"_id":904,"tag":"param","attrib":{"name":"onload","value":"true"},"text":"","tail":"\n            ","_children":[]}]}]},{"_id":905,"tag":"source-file","attrib":{"src":"src/android/WhitelistPlugin.java","target-dir":"src/org/apache/cordova/whitelist"},"text":"","tail":"\n\n        ","_children":[]},{"_id":906,"tag":"js-module","attrib":{"src":"whitelist.js","name":"whitelist"},"text":"\n            ","tail":"\n    ","_children":[{"_id":907,"tag":"runs","attrib":{},"text":"","tail":"\n        ","_children":[]}]}]}]}},"id":"cordova-plugin-whitelist","version":"1.0.0","name":"Whitelist","description":"Cordova Network Whitelist Plugin","license":"Apache 2.0","keywords":["cordova","whitelist","policy"]},"/Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist":{"filepath":"/Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/plugin.xml","dir":"/Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist","_et":{"_root":{"_id":908,"tag":"plugin","attrib":{"xmlns":"http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0","id":"cordova-plugin-whitelist","version":"1.0.0"},"text":"\n    ","tail":null,"_children":[{"_id":909,"tag":"name","attrib":{},"text":"Whitelist","tail":"\n    ","_children":[]},{"_id":910,"tag":"description","attrib":{},"text":"Cordova Network Whitelist Plugin","tail":"\n    ","_children":[]},{"_id":911,"tag":"license","attrib":{},"text":"Apache 2.0","tail":"\n    ","_children":[]},{"_id":912,"tag":"keywords","attrib":{},"text":"cordova,whitelist,policy","tail":"\n\n    ","_children":[]},{"_id":913,"tag":"engines","attrib":{},"text":"\n      ","tail":"\n\n    ","_children":[{"_id":914,"tag":"engine","attrib":{"name":"cordova-android","version":">=4.0.0-dev"},"text":"","tail":"\n    ","_children":[]}]},{"_id":915,"tag":"platform","attrib":{"name":"android"},"text":"\n        ","tail":"\n","_children":[{"_id":916,"tag":"config-file","attrib":{"target":"res/xml/config.xml","parent":"/*"},"text":"\n            ","tail":"\n\n        ","_children":[{"_id":917,"tag":"feature","attrib":{"name":"Whitelist"},"text":"\n                ","tail":"\n        ","_children":[{"_id":918,"tag":"param","attrib":{"name":"android-package","value":"org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin"},"text":"","tail":"\n                ","_children":[]},{"_id":919,"tag":"param","attrib":{"name":"onload","value":"true"},"text":"","tail":"\n            ","_children":[]}]}]},{"_id":920,"tag":"source-file","attrib":{"src":"src/android/WhitelistPlugin.java","target-dir":"src/org/apache/cordova/whitelist"},"text":"","tail":"\n\n        ","_children":[]},{"_id":921,"tag":"js-module","attrib":{"src":"whitelist.js","name":"whitelist"},"text":"\n            ","tail":"\n    ","_children":[{"_id":922,"tag":"runs","attrib":{},"text":"","tail":"\n        ","_children":[]}]}]}]}},"id":"cordova-plugin-whitelist","version":"1.0.0","name":"Whitelist","description":"Cordova Network Whitelist Plugin","license":"Apache 2.0","keywords":["cordova","whitelist","policy"]}},"_getAllCache":{}}}"
1>  Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for ios
1>  Running command: /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/version
1>  Command finished with error code 0: /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/version
1>  Install start for "cordova-plugin-whitelist" on ios.
1>  Beginning processing of action stack for ios project...
1>  Parsing ios project files...
1>  Action stack processing complete.
1>  Writing out ios project files...
1>  Preparing ios project
1>  Processing configuration changes for plugins.
1>  Iterating over installed plugins:
1>  Writing out cordova_plugins.js...
1>  Install complete for cordova-plugin-whitelist on ios.
1>  saving ios@3.9.1 into platforms.json
1>  cordova compile ios
1>  Running command: /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build --device --debug --buildConfig=/Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/build.json
1>  Reading build config file: /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/build.json
1>  Building project  : /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/BlankCordovaApp3.xcodeproj
1>      Configuration : Debug
1>      Platform      : device
1>  Build settings from command line:
1>      ARCHS = armv7 armv7s arm64
1>      CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device
1>      SDKROOT = iphoneos9.1
1>      SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
1>      VALID_ARCHS = armv7 armv7s arm64
1>
1>  Build settings from configuration file '/Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig':
1>      CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer
1>      CODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH = $(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plist
1>      TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = 1,2
1>
1>  === BUILD TARGET CordovaLib OF PROJECT CordovaLib WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
1>
1>  Check dependencies
1>
1>  Write auxiliary files
1>  /bin/mkdir -p /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/build/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Objects-normal/armv7
1>  write-file /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/build/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Cordova.LinkFileList
1>  write-file /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/build/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Cordova.hmap
1>  write-file /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/build/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Cordova-project-headers.hmap
1>  write-file /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/build/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Cordova-own-target-headers.hmap
1>  /bin/mkdir -p /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch/CordovaLib_Prefix-fohbnjmqqxzpkidjavllbqkrajxb
1>  write-file /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch/CordovaLib_Prefix-fohbnjmqqxzpkidjavllbqkrajxb/CordovaLib_Prefix.pch.pch.hash-criteria
1>  write-file /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/build/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Cordova-generated-files.hmap
1>  write-file /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/build/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Cordova-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap
1>  write-file /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/build/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Cordova-all-target-headers.hmap
1>

/***********************
 ***********************
 ***********************
 **** CpHeader, CompileC, and other build commands omitted for brevity
 ***********************
 ***********************
 ***********************/

1>  Done checking the original app
1>  + /usr/bin/zip --symlinks --verbose --recurse-paths /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device/BlankCordovaApp3.ipa .
1>  Program /usr/bin/zip returned 0 : [  adding: Payload/   (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/ (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/_CodeSignature/  (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/_CodeSignature/CodeResources (in=6931) (out=1525) (deflated 78%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/BlankCordovaApp3     (in=327264) (out=107471) (deflated 67%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/config.xml   (in=4300) (out=1157) (deflated 73%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png   (in=8040) (out=2957) (deflated 63%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/Default-667h.png (in=9694) (out=3279) (deflated 66%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/Default-736h.png (in=18046) (out=3165) (deflated 82%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/Default-Landscape-736h.png   (in=16929) (out=3502) (deflated 79%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png    (in=27628) (out=8989) (deflated 67%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/Default-Landscape~ipad.png   (in=9223) (out=2780) (deflated 70%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png (in=27505) (out=8761) (deflated 68%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/Default-Portrait~ipad.png    (in=9119) (out=2683) (deflated 71%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/Default@2x~iphone.png    (in=7318) (out=2791) (deflated 62%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/Default~iphone.png   (in=2665) (out=1038) (deflated 61%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/embedded.mobileprovision (in=7479) (out=5061) (deflated 32%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/icon-40.png  (in=208) (out=208) (stored 0%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/icon-40@2x.png   (in=526) (out=496) (deflated 6%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/icon-50.png  (in=243) (out=235) (deflated 3%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/icon-50@2x.png   (in=555) (out=509) (deflated 8%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/icon-60.png  (in=264) (out=246) (deflated 7%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/icon-60@2x.png   (in=763) (out=696) (deflated 9%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/icon-60@3x.png   (in=1083) (out=858) (deflated 21%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/icon-72.png  (in=487) (out=457) (deflated 6%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/icon-72@2x.png   (in=869) (out=774) (deflated 11%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/icon-76.png  (in=504) (out=469) (deflated 7%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/icon-76@2x.png   (in=911) (out=810) (deflated 11%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/icon-small.png   (in=190) (out=190) (stored 0%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/icon-small@2x.png    (in=279) (out=272) (deflated 3%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/icon.png (in=269) (out=262) (deflated 3%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/icon@2x.png  (in=725) (out=685) (deflated 6%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/Info.plist   (in=1676) (out=1093) (deflated 35%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/MainViewController.nib   (in=926) (out=615) (deflated 34%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/PkgInfo  (in=8) (out=8) (stored 0%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/ResourceRules.plist  (in=168) (out=117) (deflated 30%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/www/ (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/www/cordova.js   (in=58439) (out=15341) (deflated 74%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/www/cordova_plugins.js   (in=211) (out=159) (deflated 25%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/www/css/ (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/www/css/index.css    (in=14) (out=14) (stored 0%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/www/images/  (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/www/index.html   (in=1103) (out=551) (deflated 50%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/www/plugins/ (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/www/scripts/ (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/www/scripts/app.js   (in=328) (out=191) (deflated 42%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/www/scripts/index.js (in=1045) (out=491) (deflated 53%)
1>    adding: Payload/BlankCordovaApp3.app/www/scripts/platformOverrides.js (in=91) (out=80) (deflated 12%)
1>  total bytes=554026, compressed=180986 -> 67% savings
1>  ]
1>  Results at '/Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device/BlankCordovaApp3.ipa'
1>  ** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
1>  Command finished with error code 0: /Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build --device,--debug,--buildConfig=/Users/myuser/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/11580/cordovaApp/build.json
***** REMAINDER OF LOG TRUNCATED FOR SIZE RESTRICTIONS *****
```

Also, if I inspect the contents of the cordova_plugins.js file when running under iOS I see:

```
cordova.define('cordova/plugin_list', function(require, exports, module) {
module.exports = [];
module.exports.metadata = 
// TOP OF METADATA
{
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.0.0"
}
// BOTTOM OF METADATA
});
```

In my config.xml file I have the Cordova CLI version set to 5.3.3. Also, all of the fields under the iOS tab are the defaults (including Target iOS Version being blank).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue! Try renaming the "plugins" folder to "**P**lugins" & then Clean and Rebuild the solution as mentioned in the below link!

[Plugins not working on iOS - plugin files not copied to remote build machine for iOS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d37bbdf7-7100-49ff-b00f-74d330932236/plugins-not-working-on-ios-plugin-files-not-copied-to-remote-build-machine-for-ios?forum=ToolsForApacheCordova)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Seems silly but this had me scratching my head for a few hours.